# How do I make sure my notes and highlights from Google Play Books are saved when I factory reset my Android phone?

Tags: notes, google-play-books, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

I need to unlock my Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini, Android ver. 4.2.2, and I'm not sure if the notes I took on my books using the Play Books app will still be there after the reset. I need all those notes for school and it would take forever to copy them all down.

Answer (score 0):

You can check from your PC on this address that all your notes and highlights from Google Play Books are saved in the cloud and not in your device:
https://play.google.com/books/